# How to make these scoped styles reusable for 3 pages only without affecting other pages in Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There are global classes for components that we are using all around the project.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .specialPages {
      padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    }

    /deep/ .SelectorLabel {
      white-space: nowrap;
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
    }

    .Selector {
      width: 350px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .HitButton {
      width: 250px;
    }
```

We are using scoped for not effecting the these global classes and simply customize them in scope of the component if needed. However, currently, there are 3 pages are needing these styles and we don't want to affect the rest pages by making these styles global which is used only in 3 pages. How can we overcome this challenge and make these styles reusable only for these 3 pages?

Answer (score 3):

After seeing your comment about having multiple usage of the classes, I did some research and came up with a simpler way to help you with this. I think you should have the styles in a separate `.scss` file(as earlier suggested) and just import in `App.vue`. This way you can easily use the classes in the components you want to use them in. So in `App.vue`, add the below import of the styles(It could live alongside other style rules you may have in the `<style />` block in `App.vue`. Hope this helps.

```css
// App.vue
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import "path/to/myStyles.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What about adding second classes on each and based on specificity create another global scop block in one of those pages? 

For example .hitButton .large {}
And then by this approach, all styles keep in global styles block in one of those pages?

Comment: @Dave Hmm. Seems okay but the approach I suggested would encapsulate the styles so in case you need them anywhere else you could simple import them.

Comment: 2 more questions. Will this approach be safe with single-file components? And since we are adding separate scss will it generate the same unique tags for all components because otherwise, it will bring the same result as was in my sample?

Comment: @Dave This approach will be safe for SFC. Also the scoped attribute would make the styles unique so you need not worry for spillover.

Comment: I've noticed that while I inspect those both pages in each of the the same description class has different data-v-254821d7  and data-v-1d5373eee doesn't it mean that anyway in the and it duplicates the styles by the above approach which you offered?

Comment: I have modified my answer with a solution that might suit your use case. Thanks.